# Android - Multiple appWidgets playing different sounds

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm writing an android soundboard which allow the user to create multiple desktop widgets, one for each sound. I'm using an activity for the user to choose which sound he wants to create the widget for. For each widget created I store a  shared preference in the form of

```
key => "WIDGET_FILENAME_"+widgetId, value=> fileName
```

To play the sounds, I did override the `onRecieve` method on the widgetProvider class. When the desktop widget is clicked, it triggers a broadcast to this method, which gets the widget id from the intent and then loads the shared preference associated with the widget:

```
int appWidgetId =  intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                                     AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

The problem is: The widgetId is always the same, no matter which widget is clicked, causing the same sound to be played.

Any idea or guidance on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

1. In your AppWidgetProviderClass, declare your Intent as follows:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class)
           .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
           .putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
   ```
2. ...and PendingIntent

   ```
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent,
                                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   ```
3. In the Activity class, after getting the appWidgetId you want to update:

   ```
   int currentWidgetId = this.getIntent().getIntExtra(
          AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
   ```
4. ...you can use a function similar to this one:

   ```
   private void updateWidgetView() {
       views = new RemoteViews(YourWidget.class.getPackage().getName(),
                               R.layout.main_widget);
       mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
       views.setTextViewText(R.id.some_text_view, someText);
       // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
       mgr.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views);
   }
   ```

Comment: Great ! really helped me to figure the same problem I had. The interesting part is that what made the difference was using the appWidgetId as the requestCode while in the documentation it says that this is never used...

Comment: @Rabi, do you have a more complete code that you could share? I have been trying to implement this into my code and it just isn't working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607518/android-appwidget-multiple-instances

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem right now and with that code the problem is gone, Think that the widgetAppId in the Intent and the flag Create new will make this Intent always unique.