# Android appWidget multiple instances

Tags: android, android-appwidget

This question is pretty much a duplicate of [Android - Multiple appWidgets playing different sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225197/android-multiple-appwidgets-playing-diferent-sounds), but my code isn't working. I am adding an intent extra with the widget id, with log statements to prove it, but whenever I click on one of my widgets when there are multiple instances of it, I only get the last appWidgetId. It looks like the intent of the first widget is changing after the second one is added. If the code in that other post should work, then I must be overlooking something because I believe mine is set up pretty much the same way.

```
 public class PhcaAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
     private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "com.skipmorrow.phca.PhcaAppWidgetProvider.WIDGET_CLICKED";
     private final String widgetPageName = "_widget";
     private static final String PREFS_NAME = "PHCA";
     private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "prefix_";
     private static String MY_DEBUG = "PhcaAppWidget";

     @Override
     public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
             int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.onUpdate");
     }

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.onReceive(); action = " + intentAction);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        // make a list of all extras, just so I can see what is in there...
        if (extras!=null) {
            Set<String> ks = extras.keySet();
            Iterator<String> iterator = ks.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String s = iterator.next();
                Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.Key found: " + s);
            }
        }
        else {
          Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.extras was null");
        }

            int[] appWidgetIds1 = intent.getIntArrayExtra("appWidgetIds");

            if (extras!=null && extras.containsKey("appWidgetIds")){
                // sometimes the intent comes back with an array of appWidgetIds, and sometimes the appWidgetId is stored
                // in the one extra "appWidgetId" Clicks never come with the array of appWidgetIds. They always come by
                // themselves
                Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.Intent extras does contain a key appWidgetIds");
                if (appWidgetIds1!=null) Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.Intent int array appWidgetIds1 size is " + appWidgetIds1.length);
                for (int i = 0; i<appWidgetIds1.length; i++) {
                    int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds1[i];
                    Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.Intent appWidgetIds1[" + i + "] = " + appWidgetId);
                    if (intentAction.equals("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE")) {
                        Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.APPWIDGET UPDATE");
                        updateWidgetState(context, intentAction, appWidgetId);
                    } else if (intentAction.equals("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED")) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                    else {
                        super.onReceive(context, intent);
                    }
                }
            } else {

            String intentData = intent.getDataString();
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.intent data = " + intentData);


            Integer appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra("appWidgetId", -1);
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.appWidgetId = " + appWidgetId);

            if (intentAction.equals(ACTION_CLICK)) {
                Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.Clicked");
                SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                Integer objNum = myPrefs.getInt(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, -1);
                Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.ObjNum = " + objNum);
                if (objNum > -1) {
                    Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.Executing...");
                    PageAction pa = (PageAction) CommonActivity.GetPageObjectAtIndex(context, widgetPageName, objNum);
                    pa.ExecuteActionFromWidgetClick(context);
                }
            }
            else {
                super.onReceive(context, intent);
            } 
            }
     }

     public static void updateWidgetState(Context paramContext, String paramString, Integer appWidgetId)
     {
        Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.updateWidgetState; appWidgetId = " + appWidgetId + "; paramString = " + paramString);
        RemoteViews localRemoteViews = buildUpdate(paramContext, paramString, appWidgetId);
        ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName(paramContext, PhcaAppWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext).updateAppWidget(localComponentName, localRemoteViews);
     }



     private static RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context ctx, String paramString, Integer appWidgetId)
     {
        Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.buildUpdate(); appWidgetId = " + appWidgetId + "; paramString = " + paramString);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.phca_appwidget);
        if (paramString.equals("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE")) {
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.buildUpdate().. APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, PhcaAppWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_CLICK);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                Uri.parse("ABCD" + "://widget/id/")
                ,String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
            intent.setData(data);
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.Added intent extra \"" +  AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID + "\" = " + appWidgetId);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, appWidgetId, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.phca_appwidget_layout, pendingIntent);
        }
        if(paramString.equals(ACTION_CLICK))
        {
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Provider.buildUpdate().. CLICKED");
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "ACTION_CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return views; 
    }
 }
```

I do have a configuration activity (a ListActivity) Here's my onListItemClick:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onListItemClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Configurator.onListItemClick");
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    prefs.putInt(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + mAppWidgetId, position);
    prefs.commit();
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Configurator.Prefs.commit()");

    // Push widget update to surface with newly set prefix
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Configurator.calling updateWidgetState with appWidgetId = " + mAppWidgetId);
    PhcaAppWidgetProvider.updateWidgetState(getApplicationContext(), "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE", mAppWidgetId);
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Configurator.updateWidgetState complete");
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Uri.parse("ABCD" + "://widget/id/")
            ,String.valueOf(mAppWidgetId));
    resultValue.setData(data);
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    Log.d(MY_DEBUG, "Configurator.Creating widget with id = " + mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();
}
```

I've been working on this for two days and I do hope that someone can point out the err of my ways. A virtual e-beer awaits the person who can solve this :)

Comment: I had a feeling this one wouldn't draw too many comments and answers. Perhaps someone has some working code complete they could share with me?

Answer (score 5):

I tried to look over your code but did not find why it doesn't work for you except I found some other bugs in your code. Anyway I have built a quick working code that you can try out.

**WidgetProvider.java**

```
package com.example.helloclickablewidget;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static final String WIDGET_CLICKED = "com.example.helloclickablewidget.WIDGET_CLICKED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action != null && action.equals(WIDGET_CLICKED)) {
            int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Widget clicked. ID: " + widgetId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(WIDGET_CLICKED);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text, pendingIntent);
            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

}
```

**layout/widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/app_name" >
</TextView>
```

**xml/widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest package="com.example.helloclickablewidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="WidgetProvider" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.example.helloclickablewidget.WIDGET_CLICKED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work, I've posted a question, and since it looks like you got a pretty good hang of widget, would you consider taking a look at it, there's a 50 rep bounty on it. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483131/update-textview-text-size-on-appwidget

Comment: I just notice your comment and looks like you got an answer already. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing these lines:

```
Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Uri.parse("ABCD" + "://widget/id/")
            ,String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
        intent.setData(data);
```

With:

```
intent.setData(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.EMPTY, appWidgetId));
```