# Passing date/string value from configure class to widgetprovider

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm trying to pass a string value from a widget configuration class to appWidgetProvider class. I've read that you pass a string between classes like this:

In current activity, create an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra(key, value);
startActivity(i);
```

then in the other activity, retrieve those values.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString(key);
}
```

(for the "key" I declared a string)

but when writing the retrieve code into my appWidget provider is gives me an error saying: The method getIntent() is undefined for the type Widget

what do I do?

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `Widget` class is the app widget provider class. You can't call `getIntent()` here because `getIntent()` is a method of the `Activity` class

But I don't understand - how/why are you calling the app widget provider from your configuration activity? Intents the `AppWidgetProvider` class receives are created by the Android framework, not by you.

Comment: Well I'm new to programming, so I don't know what's going on at all times. But how ells can I get the value of a string in widget class which is set in my config class

Comment: You shouldn't. Instead, you perform any configuration required for the app widget **inside** the app widget configuration activity, then update it. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

Comment: yes I am doing that, I'm just having trouble updating it, so I thought I'd try something ells. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483131/update-textview-text-size-on-appwidget